# Issue with Umbraco nforum

Tags: umbraco

I have some issues with using nforum. Please see screenshots bellow

[image]
[image]

I don't know why I receive this error only on this part and everything else on forum works great?

Answer (score 0):

If you change in the file "web.config"

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
```

to

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

you'll get more information what the real error is...

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for prompt reply! I did as you suggested and this is the error I receive now: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/882x503q90/11/bwsc.jpg Can you help me with this? Thanks, MC

Comment: Set debug to true as described in the error message, to receive more information.

Comment: Hello, I didn't notice that, sorry;( I made correction and this points to error "Line 31:         <a href="<%=UmbracoAppHelpers.GetLoginPage().Url%>"><%=UmbracoAppHelpers.GetLoginPage().Name%></a> /" Please see screenshot https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x315q90/691/b1d0.jpg I am not sure why is is this error showing, everything else is working fine? Thanks, MC

Comment: Seems like your GetLoginPage() method is returning null.  Have you tried attaching a debugger to verify that you GetLoginPage() method is working correctly?

Comment: Problem was because I wasn't logged here is the new error;( http://our.umbraco.org/media/upload/b601fc27-c556-42db-af25-6c3bbaf7dc12/error.jpg Any suggestions? BR, Adi